# html angular table - pivot-like display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Can someone help me figure out how to accomplish the following in html/angular/bootstrap?

I have data like the following:

[image]

On my page, I would like to display it this way:

[image]

Comment: What about converting your source data to how you need (pivot it) and then display in grid?

Comment: I've done exactly that using [pivottable.js](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable). Of course in order to take it to angular, you should wrap it with a directive

Comment: @G_S I thought about that as well.  However, how would you handle binding it?  I thought about converting the array of objects into an array of arrays then flipping the rows and columns.  However, after that point I'm stuck!

Comment: @lealceldeiro thanks for fixing my post.  Not enough cred to display images here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angularjs this is what you need to be doing:

> Code in controller

```
$scope.data = [ { OrderDate: "1/15/2018", Quantity: 10, Price: "$ 50" },
                { OrderDate: "1/16/2018", Quantity: 20, Price: "$ 100" },
                { OrderDate: "1/17/2018", Quantity: 30, Price: "$ 150" }
              ];
```

> Code on html page:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <tbody>
     <tr data-ng-repeat="(key, val) in data[0]">
         <th>
             {{ key }}
         </th>
         <td data-ng-repeat="row in data">
             {{ row[key] }}
         </td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Output will be like this

[image]

This is the code to add padding for every 10th row:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
      app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
        
          $scope.data = [
            {column_1: "1,1",column_2: "1,2",column_3: "1,3",column_4: "1,4",column_5: "1,5",column_6: "1,6",column_7: "1,7",column_8: "1,8",column_9: "1,9",column_10: "1,10",column_11: "1,11",column_12: "1,12",column_13: "1,13",column_14: "1,14",column_15: "1,15",column_16: "1,16",column_17: "1,17",column_18: "1,18",column_19: "1,19",column_20: "1,20",column_21: "1,21",column_22: "1,22",column_23: "1,23",column_24: "1,24",column_25: "1,25",column_26: "1,26",column_27: "1,27",column_28: "1,28",column_29: "1,29",column_30: "1,30"},
            {column_1: "2,1",column_2: "2,2",column_3: "2,3",column_4: "2,4",column_5: "2,5",column_6: "2,6",column_7: "2,7",column_8: "2,8",column_9: "2,9",column_10: "2,10",column_11: "2,11",column_12: "2,12",column_13: "2,13",column_14: "2,14",column_15: "2,15",column_16: "2,16",column_17: "2,17",column_18: "2,18",column_19: "2,19",column_20: "2,20",column_21: "2,21",column_22: "2,22",column_23: "2,23",column_24: "2,24",column_25: "2,25",column_26: "2,26",column_27: "2,27",column_28: "2,28",column_29: "2,29",column_30: "2,30"}];
          });
      }());
  </script>
  <style>
    table tr:nth-of-type(10n) td{
        padding-bottom: 50px;
    }
    
    table td, table th{
      border: 1px solid #ffffff !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="(key, val) in data[0]" class="test">
        <th>
          {{ key }}
        </th>
        <td data-ng-repeat="row in data">
          {{ row[key] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This kinda works.  Only problem is formatting is tricky.  I also need to insert empty rows in between.  My actualy table has over 30 columns (so 30 rows) and the user wants the resulting rows separated by empty rows (e.g. rows 1- 10, then empty row, rows 11-25, then empty row, then the rest).

Comment: The space between the tables can be easily handled by css